# Bash Script with Azure CLI

Tags: bash, azure, shell, azure-cli, az

I am new to shell scripting.
I am trying to use

`az sig image-version list`

command from azure which should return a list of versions and storing it into a list/array. So I can step through the list in a for loop.

```
VERSIONS_LIST="$(az sig image-version list --gallery-image-definition $GALLERY_IMAGE_NAME --gallery-name $GALLERY_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)`"
```

However, I am not sure if the command returns more than just the versions. If so how can I only take part of the output?

I am also having issue with displaying the populated list. I believe my syntax of using the azure cli to store in the list is wrong. any guidance is much appreciated.

```
echo VERSION_LIST
```

Am I storing the list correctly into the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Global Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sig/image-version?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sig-image-version-list-optional-parameters) `--query` and `--output` to query the version list with [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) from the output of `az sig image-version list` then you can store the output as a variable in bash like this without double quotation marks,

```
VERSIONS_LIST=$(az sig image-version list --gallery-image-definition $GALLERY_IMAGE_NAME --gallery-name $GALLERY_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --query "xxx" --output tsv)
```

Then you can check the variable with command `echo $VERSIONS_LIST`. If you want to run for loop, you may do it like this,

```
for version in $VERSIONS_LIST
do
    echo $version

done
```

For example, here is a bash script with CLI 2.0. See [this blog](https://azurecitadel.com/prereqs/cli/cli-4-bash/) for more details.

```
#!/bin/bash
rgName=nancytest
vmlist=$(az vm list -g $rgName --query "[].name" -o tsv)

for vm in  $vmlist
do

vmLocation=$(az vm show -g $rgName -n $vm --query "location" -o tsv)
echo $vm,$vmLocation

done
```

See [bash for loop examples](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/).

Comment: Hello Nancy, thank you so much for the help on using JMESPath for this issue. It was actually --query "[].name" for the image version. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it helps you. I don't have a test image environment. If my reply actually points you in the right direction, you could accept it.